# Unable to connect to data source 'DataSource'.ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC]

Tags: sql, mariadb, odbc, ssrs

Estoy intentando conectarme desde Windows 8.1 64 bits con el Visual Studio SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) a una base de datos mariadb que esta corriendo en un servidor linux 64 bits, estoy probando con los drivers ODBC.

El DSN lo hago sin problemas pero cuando intento agregar el DataSource desde Visual Studio me aparece el siguiente error:

> Unable to connect to data source 'DataSource'.ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] La arquitectura del DSN especificado no coincide entre el controlador y la aplicación.

Me gustaría saber que driver necesito y si es posible la conexión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es usar el driver de 32 bits MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver
Con este driver funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

Este es un problema "conocido" al instalar el driver [ODBC](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)

> La arquitectura del
>   DSN especificado no coincide entre el controlador y la aplicación

Mencionas que usas Windows 8.1, pero incluso este problema se puede presentar hasta  Windows 10 como fue en mi caso, lo que se debe realizar es, dependiendo del sistema operativo descargar e **instalar la versión para 32 bits del driver aunque el Sistema operativo sea de 64 bits**:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.3.html

Esto también puede aplicar además de MySQL para MS SQL Server.